# how to add 3d models dynamically in glsurface view renderer in android

Tags: android, opengl-es, augmented-reality, glsurfaceview, jpct

In my Augmented reality application I need to render 3D model over a marker. with predefined/ initialized 3d model i can show teapot over a marker detecion. but now I want to replace it with another 3d model dynamically from sd card on some trigger event like button click. is there any suggestion or guideline how i can implement it? I am using JPCT-AE for 3d models.

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After so much research and trial and errors finally i got it to work.
When I asked this question I wanted to display 3d model over marker dynamically by downloading it from remote server on SD card and then render it.
you could do it using Rajawali api like this

```
getCurrentScene().removeChild(myCurrentObj);
ObjParser parser = new ObjParser(this, 'mydir\myfile.obj');
parser.parse();
getCurrentScene().addChild(parser.getParsedObject());
```