# User defined target image and user defined model at run time using vuforia

Tags: augmented-reality, vuforia

How can I download a 3d model from web and then augment it on user defined target image in **Vuforia** at run time?

Using **UserDefineTarget** image in **Vuforia** we can only augment predefined 3d model.

But what I want to do is to augment any desired 3d model that can be download from web and then can augment on user defined target image at **run time**.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really related to Vuforia or AR specifically - UserDefinedTarget allows you to know where to draw what you want. This is a pure OpenGl question.

Basically, this should not be a big deal - download the 3d model file, and load it from that file and parse it (rather than load the model from a hard-coded file) to get all the model data.

Here you can find an example using the Rajawali library (Android), but you should be able to find other ways quite easily:
[how to add 3d models dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16900549/how-to-add-3d-models-dynamically-in-glsurface-view-renderer-in-android)